# WSO2 BPS: How to pass Header values as a part of a Message in BPEL Invoke

Tags: bpel, wso2

My web service operation is defined like below. Where I have a header parameter as well.

```
public void method(@WebParam(name="OrderNo", mode=WebParam.Mode.IN) String order_no_,
                    @WebParam(name="user", mode=WebParam.Mode.IN, header=true) String user)
```

Now when I deploy this service I get a WSDL which looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<wsdl:definitions ... >
    <wsdl:types>
        </xs:schema>
            ...
            <xs:element name="method" type="tns:method"></xs:element>
            <xs:complexType name="method">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="OrderNo" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>  
            ...
            <xs:element name="user" nillable="true" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            ...
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    ...
    <wsdl:message name="method">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:method" name="parameters" />
        <wsdl:part element="tns:user" name="user" />
    </wsdl:message>
    ...
    <wsdl:portType name="CustomerOrderService">
        <wsdl:operation name="method">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:method" name="method" />
            <wsdl:output ... /> 
            <wsdl:fault ... />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    ...
    <wsdl:binding name="OrderSoapBinding" type="tns:OrderService">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" /> 
        <wsdl:operation name="method">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" /> 
            <wsdl:input name="method">
                <soap:header message="tns:method" part="user" use="literal" /> 
                <soap:body parts="parameters" use="literal" /> 
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="...">
                <soap:body use="literal" /> 
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="...">
                ...
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

As you can see the header is part of the message used as input for the service request. Hwen I use soap UI to test this WSDL it generated a proper soap message with the "user" property as part of the header.

When I use this service as a partner link in a Carbon BPEL process, and assign a value to the "user" part in the invoke message, the value is not included in the header.

```
<bpel:variable name="method_Input" messageType="ns0:method" />  

<bpel:assign name="...">
   ...
   <bpel:copy>
      <bpel:from>$input.payload/tns:TaskReceiver</bpel:from>
      <bpel:to>$method_Input.user</bpel:to>
   </bpel:copy>
</bpel:assign>
```

You can see that the message part is assigned the proper value,

[image: Console information]

The problem is this message part which is bound to the header of of the soap message is never included in the soap header.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <method xmlns="http://customerorder.service.test/">
            <OrderNo xmlns="">ORD00011</OrderNo>
        </method>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks in advance to any help provided.